# save scroll position inside div after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to save the scroll position inside a div ,so that after reload it will load in the same position.
In my project im using [this](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin to scroll to element inside a div by its title. the current way i'm using this plugin is this:

```
$("#wrapper").scrollTo($(".active>.placementWrapper>.placementName[title='" + placementName + "']"));
  var scrollToPos = placementName;
  localStorage.setItem("scrollToPos", scrollToPos);
```

but as you can see, i use element's title to get the position i need to scroll to, so when im scrolling with the mouse for example, the position won't update.

this is the code of the plugin:

```
$.fn.scrollTo = function( target, options, callback ){
  if(typeof options == 'function' && arguments.length == 2){ callback = options; options = target; }
  var settings = $.extend({
    scrollTarget  : target,
    offsetTop     : 50,
    duration      : 500,
    easing        : 'swing'
  }, options);
  return this.each(function(){
    var scrollPane = $(this);
    var scrollTarget = (typeof settings.scrollTarget == "number") ? settings.scrollTarget : $(settings.scrollTarget);
    var scrollY = (typeof scrollTarget == "number") ? scrollTarget : scrollTarget.offset().top + scrollPane.scrollTop() - parseInt(settings.offsetTop);
    scrollPane.animate({scrollTop : scrollY }, parseInt(settings.duration), settings.easing, function(){
      if (typeof callback == 'function') { callback.call(this); }
    });
  });
}
```

bottom line, any idea how can i save the last position inside the `#wrapper` ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Try using just this to store.:

```
<div id="test" style="height:460px;"></div>

<script>

localStorage.hval=(document).getElementById("test").style.height;

</script>
```

To get the value again,

```
localStorage.getItem("hval");
```

You can replace `hval` with pretty much anything you want.To check the LocalStorage, go to the Dev tools>Resources>Local Storage